# where is the start file for oracle jdeveloper in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jdeveloper

I recently installed oracle jdeveloper 11g in my home directory on Ubuntu Linux
(the installer was a .jar file)
and the installer puts the files in `~/Oracle/Middleware/...`

since it creates no icons on my desktop
my question is that were is the start file to start the jdeveloper program??
(where should I look for the launcher file?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 MW_HOME/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev
```

More details about the installation on Unix [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/install.111240/e17074/ojdig.htm#OJDIG120).